# Animating an SVG Group

Tags: css, animation, svg

I currently have the following SVG:

```
<svg class="tower owner" height="60" width="60" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <g transform="translate(75 75)" opacity="1">
        <ellipse class="border" cx="0" cy="0" fill="#222" rx="65" ry="65" stroke-width="5"></ellipse>
        <g class="rotatable" style="transform: rotate(5.497787143782138rad); transition: transform 2s;">
            <rect fill="#aaa" height="50" stroke-width="7" stroke="#181818" width="40" x="-20" y="-80"></rect>
            <rect fill="#555" height="58" rx="12" ry="10" width="78" x="-39" y="-25"></rect>
            <rect fill="#ffe56d" height="46.4" y="-13.399999999999999" rx="12" ry="12" width="78" x="-39"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I am currently animating a rotation on `g.rotatable` however I would like to use `<animateTransform>` if possible, and I haven't figured out how.

I have tried placing it at the start of the group, at the bottom of it, and even after it, however none have any affect.

```
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" dur="5s" keyTimes="0;0.4;0.75;1" repeatCount="indefinite" type="rotate" values="315deg;90deg;200deg;315deg" calcMode="linear"></animateTransform>
```

Since I've never really worked with SVGs or animating them, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
svg.tower .rotatable {
    animation: tower 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes tower {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(315deg);
    }
    40% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(200deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(315deg);
    }
}
```

Above is my current CSS animation.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, so I can fix my mistakes, or if it's even possible, so I can potentially give up this line of action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note:** You may want to reconsider using SMIL animations instead of CSS animations because [Chrome has deprecated support for SMIL animations from v45](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL).

There were two problems in your code and they are as follows:

1. The [`rotate` transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) in SVG just takes the degree number as value and doesn't need the `deg` suffix to be added to it. In addition a transform origin can also be specified (2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> param) but it is not mandatory.
2. There was a `style='transform: rotate(...)'` on the `.rotatable` element. The CSS overrides the `animateTransform` and so you don't get to see any rotation. Avoid this `style`setting. If there is a need for an initial rotation you could probably use SVG's `transform` attribute.

Below is a working demo:

```html
<svg class="tower owner" height="60" width="60" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <g transform="translate(75 75)" opacity="1">
    <ellipse class="border" cx="0" cy="0" fill="#222" rx="65" ry="65" stroke-width="5"></ellipse>
    <g class="rotatable" transform="rotate(315)">
      <rect fill="#aaa" height="50" stroke-width="7" stroke="#181818" width="40" x="-20" y="-80"></rect>
      <rect fill="#555" height="58" rx="12" ry="10" width="78" x="-39" y="-25"></rect>
      <rect fill="#ffe56d" height="46.4" y="-13.399999999999999" rx="12" ry="12" width="78" x="-39"></rect>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" dur="5s" keyTimes="0;0.4;0.75;1" repeatCount="indefinite" type="rotate" values="315;90;200;315" calcMode="linear"></animateTransform>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL:

_Although Chrome 45 deprecated SMIL in favor of CSS animations and Web animations, the Chrome developers have since [suspended](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/YGEJBsjUAwAJ) that deprecation._